# Reload a python script after an auto selenium error

Tags: python, selenium

Hi guys I have a hard time making a script.

I have a python script using selenium

I am doing automation on a site, the script needs to be running on that site for a long time.

The problem is that the site times out, the robot returns an error and stops executing.

I need that when this happens close all windows and reconnect to the site again

site timeout is = 30min

if anyone can help me it will help a lot!!!

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui

URL = 'https://XXXXXXX'
URL2 = 'https://XXXXXX'

user = 'user12345'
password = 'password12345'
class Web:
  browser = webdriver.Ie(URL)
  browser.find_element_by_name('login').send_keys(user)
  browser.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)

  pyautogui.moveTo(121,134)# here I open a login window so I can use another link that I need to use
  pyautogui.click(121,134)

  browser.execute_script("window.open()")
  browser.switch-to.frame(browser.window_handles[1])
  browser.get(URL2)

  with open(tabela, "r") as leitor:
    reader = csv.DictReader(leitor, delimiter=';')
    for linha in reader:
        folder = linha['folder']
        try:
          browser.find_element_by_id('field').send_keys(folder)
          browser.find_element_by_id('save').click()
        except:
           with open('falied.txt', 'a') as wirter:
                writer.write(folder)
                writer.close()
    browser.quit()
  if __name__ == '__main__':
       Web()
```

from now on he needs to be running the code inside the page

this code is an example similar to my original code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your part of code with the code below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            Web()
        Except:
            browser.quit()
```

As you can see we're calling it in `while True` which means it'll run indefinitely `browser.quit()` will close the selenium.